# Rails assets not precompiling in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, assets

I'm using [Datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and [Slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider). I include them in my Gemfile

```
gem 'datetimepicker-rails', github: 'zpaulovics/datetimepicker-rails', branch: 'master', submodules: true
source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  # gem 'rails-assets-select2-bootstrap-css'
  gem 'rails-assets-seiyria-bootstrap-slider'
end
```

In my `application.js`

```
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require pickers

//= require seiyria-bootstrap-slider
```

This works great in development, but when I run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` on the server (capistrano deploy or by hand) these, and others don't seem to get pulled in. Chrome complains specifically about these two first.

I know I could put the line `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js )` and then do a `=javascript_include_tag :XXXX`, but this defeats the purpose of sprockets/manifest right?

My understanding with sprockets/manifest is when I require it in my `application.js` it'll be included with the deploy so the client hits the server less.

Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT**
Traced the problem to the `uglifier` gem. When I remove/comment out `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier` and recompile the JS starts working again.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want to serve static (precompiled) assets from `public` directory of rails, ensure that `config.serve_static_assets = true`. Another possible problem - you run `assets:precompile` for `development` by default - specify environment e.g. `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

Comment: @AlkH, sorry I should have stated, this is done on the production server so `RAILS_ENV=production` is being applied. Edited post

Comment: Are you only linking to application.js in your html? Does the precompiled application.js contain these two dependencies?

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I traced it to the uglifier gem. Updated question

Comment: Possibly a bug in uglifier then - I'd make sure you have the latest version and check their site for any known issues

Answer (score 7):

this is because things work differently in development as compared to production.
few thing to note:-

1. No CSS or JS files will be available to your app through the asset pipeline unless they are included in other files **OR** listed in the `config.precompile` directive.Only `application.css` and `application.js` are available by default of all the CSS and JS files.
2. Every file that is not a Javascript file or CSS file that is in the app/assets folder will be copied by **Rails** into the `public/assets` folder when you compile your assets.So if you want to add some web fonts, you could make an app/assets/fonts/ folder and put your fonts in there, these will then be copied to `public/assets/fonts` folder when you compile your assets. Note that your `app/assets/stylesheets/fonts.css.scss` file that references those fonts will **NOT** be copied over unless you either added it to the `config.assets.precompile` directive or required it from your `application.css`
3. for `config.assets.compile`...If it is set to "true" (which it is by default in development) then **Rails** will try to find a Javascript or CSS file by first looking in the `public/assets` directory and if it can't find it, will hunt through your `app/assets` folder looking for the file. If it finds it in `app/assets` it will go ahead and compile on the fly and then serve this asset up.

The problem with this is that you don't notice it happening in development, then you commit everything and push to production and BOOM, everything is broken with 500 errors because **production** has `config.assets.compile` set to "false"**.This prevents the app from "falling back" and trying to load the file directly instead of using the asset pipeline.**

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false
```

*Why don't you just have this set to "true" in every environment? Well, because it is sloooooow. And you don't want slow in production*

4. Run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean assets:precompile`
5. check public/assets directory and verify that assets are compiled..if its not empty...that means asset pipeline is working but path is not correct.use [asset_helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html) to set the path of assets in css files.

Comment: Addition about path - sometimes app is deployed under some route, not in `/` - in such cases precompile assets with variable `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=$prefix_path`

Comment: To #1, isn't that what I am doing by saying `//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker` in the `application.js` such that I don't have to do `config.assets.compile = false`? Also, made a note this is on the production server (capistrano deploy & by hand on server)